# User:Register, checkboxes for multiple mailing lists?

Tags: solspace-user

I'm trying to implement checkboxes to allow new members to signup for multiple mailing lists instead of the multiple select dropmenu option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing if you are using EE's Mailing Listing with with tag `exp:mailinglist:form`, it wouldn't be possible to signup for multiple mailing lists at once. Are you using any other third party addon by which you are doing it via multiple select drop down options?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to create a **select** field for mailinglists in `{exp:user:register}`. You can modify the code in the docs (http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/register/#select_mailing_lists) for your own purposes, for example to something like:

```
{select_mailing_lists}
<input type="checkbox" name="mailinglist_subscribe[]" value="{list_id}" id="mailing_list_{list_id}" /> <label for="mailing_list_{list_id}">{list_title}</label>
{/select_mailing_lists}
```

The key here (and in many EE forms) is to pass the right name="". Please note the brackets `[]` in each field's name="" attribute. This allows for multiple selected mailing lists to be submitted with the form.